# Affiliate system built on top of Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, affiliate, affiliates

I'm trying to build an affiliate system. I currently have a Stripe Plan setup for customers that bills them monthly. I'd like to give a percentage-based commission to affiliates.

Is there a way to automatically pay stripe customer when another customer gets billed off of this plan? Is this possible to configure in a existing Stripe plan?

Alternatively, is there a way to setup a Stripe plan for an affiliate that *pays* them rather than *charge* them every month? I could subscribe the affiliates to such a plan, but I would also need a way to multiply the payment based on how many customers they referred.

What's the solution?

Comment: This might be a good question for #stripe IRC channel if you have not asked it there already...

Answer (score 2):

If your affiliates have Stripe you can create a Transfer to the connected account using `destination`

```
// Create a Charge:
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 1000,
  "currency" => "eur",
  "source" => $token,
  "transfer_group" => "ORDER42",
));

// Create a Transfer to the connected account (later):
$transfer = \Stripe\Transfer::create(array(
  "amount" => 877,
  "currency" => "eur",
  "destination" => "{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}",
  "transfer_group" => "ORDER42",
));
```

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers

Alternatively you can use the `application_fee` to take an application fee on charges and subscriptions:

```
// Create a Charge:
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 1000,
  "currency" => "eur",
  "source" => $token,
  "application_fee" => 123,
), array("stripe_account" => "{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}"));
```

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges#collecting-fees

Comment: This answer makes sense. Perhaps also see what the stripe devs over at the stripe irc channel would recommend. (I am not sure how well represented they are on SO).

Answer (score 0):

You can add an invoice item with negative amount so affiliate has to pay less on next subscription charge (https://stripe.com/docs/api#invoiceitems).

I don't think you can pay your customers via Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the transfers API to pay out to other accounts than your own through their API:

https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/sending-transfers